# By using angular routing not getting default route selected

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I am using routerLinkActive for default route selected along with this I am also showing image. On initial loading image is not coming. By changing tabs, the image is showing properly.

Below is my code:

**app routing file:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'adminsidebar',
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  component: SidebarComponent,
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ActivityDashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'activitydashboard',
    component: ActivityDashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'therapistdashboard',
    component: TherapistDashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'reviewapprovaldashboard',
    component: ReviewApprovalComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'feedbackdashboard',
    component: FeedbackComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'clientdashboard',
    component: ClientdashboardComponent
  }]
}]
```

**sidebarcomponent.ts:**

```
<li id="activity" [routerLink]="['./activitydashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['Active']" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''" #rla="routerLinkActive" class="Active pointer">
  <p class="link-items pointer">
    <img *ngIf="!rla.isActive" src="/assets/img/activity-blue-retina.png" class="links-img" alt=""> {{ rla.isActive }}
    <img *ngIf="rla.isActive" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''" src="/assets/img/activity-white-retina.png" class="links-img" data-srcset="/assets/img/activity-white@2x.png,/assets/img/activity-white@3x.png" alt="">
    <span class="list-labels"> Activity </span>
  </p>
</li>
```

As I have taken two image and displaying on `rla.isActive` value. On Init `rla.IsActive` always comes false.

How to resolve this. Please help me out..

Comment: If you remove this : { path:'', component: ActivityDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, it works properly?

Comment: No, @Robertgarcia

Answer (score 0):

First path will redirect to your default path. Here `redirectTo` will redirect you to your "adminsidebar" route.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo:'adminsidebar' , pathMatch:'full'},
 { path: 'adminsidebar', canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ], component:SidebarComponent , children:[
        { path:'', component: ActivityDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path:'activitydashboard', component: ActivityDashboardComponent },
        { path:'therapistdashboard', component:TherapistDashboardComponent},
        { path:'reviewapprovaldashboard', component:ReviewApprovalComponent},
        { path:'feedbackdashboard' , component:FeedbackComponent},
        { path:'clientdashboard' , component:ClientdashboardComponent},
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: As I described in my question my concern is for rla -> routerLinkActive. On initial rla comes false. But defaultly it should come true which is not coming. On base on that rla value I am showing image.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use empty path and wildcard path to redirect to your specific path. 
As per the angular guide follow these instruction

The ** path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo:'adminsidebar' , pathMatch:'full'},
{ path: '**', redirectTo:'adminsidebar' , pathMatch:'full'},
 { path: 'adminsidebar', canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ], component:SidebarComponent , children:[
        { path:'', component: ActivityDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path:'activitydashboard', component: ActivityDashboardComponent },
        { path:'therapistdashboard', component:TherapistDashboardComponent},
        { path:'reviewapprovaldashboard', component:ReviewApprovalComponent},
        { path:'feedbackdashboard' , component:FeedbackComponent},
        { path:'clientdashboard' , component:ClientdashboardComponent},
    ]
  }
]
```